# Using svnlook cat in pre-commit hook

Tags: svn

I am trying to cat the contents of .svn/entries file in a pre-commit hook.

I am running this command.

```
svnlook cat /var/www/svn/testrepo/   branches/.svn/entries
```

but I am getting the following error

```
svnlook: Path 'branches/.svn/entries' does not exist
```

My repo structure is as follows.

trunk
branches
tags

am i missing some thing??

my intention is to get the branch url.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument for `svnlook cat` is a path in the repository specified by the first argument. E.g.: `svnlook cat /var/www/svn/testrepo branches/somebranch/file.txt`.

`branches/.svn/entries` is **not** a path in SVN repository. It may be a "bookkeeping" file in an SVN **working copy**.

Comment: tanx for the reply.

is there ny way to get "svn info" like output using "svnlook info"

I really want to get the url of the branch to be used in a precommit hook.

Comment: Theoretically, there is no way for `svnlook` to deduce the URL (unless you store it somewhere when invoking the server). The URL depends on the way you run the server (consider `--listen-host` option for `svnserve`) as well as on the host name.